# What should I say instead of "you first"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, compliment

Are there any specific phrases for this situations below:

1. When I am approaching to pickup something from a store shelf and somebody else is also doing same at the same time and I want to say: "you take it".
2. When I reach to a door with another guy at the same time and I want to say: "you go first".
3. When I want to speak and somebody else also wants do it at the moment and I want to say "you speak first".

Comment: There's an established phrase: [***After you***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/after_you); *a polite formula used to suggest that someone goes in front of or takes a turn before oneself.* This would work well for (2) and (3), but for (1), if there's only one item left on the shelf that both of you need, you could say something like, "Please, *you* take it." (with a smile). Otherwise, you can use *after you* for (1) as well.

Comment: See also: [What means "after you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/219001/what-means-after-you) on ELL (our sister site).

Comment: This question would be more at home on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Justin in the comments, I think "[After you](https://www.lexico.com/definition/after_you)" could work.

> A polite formula used to suggest that someone goes in front of or takes a turn before oneself.
>
> ‘No, please, **after you**.’
> ‘Please, I insist, you go first.’

(Lexico)